# Triggering multiple lambda functions from one SQS trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm not sure if I understand AWS Lambda - SQS triggers correctly. Can I possibly configure it in such a way that one SQS queue can trigger different lambda functions depending on the message body or a message attribute?

**My use case:** I have three different lambda functions (processCricket, processFootball, processTennis) each of which perform a unique function. I have a single queue (processGame) which receives messages. Each message on the queue has a attribute "type" which is either "Cricket", "Football" or "Tennis". Can I invoke a different lambda function depending on the "type" on the message?

**Option 1:** Configure SQS to trigger a different lambda function depending on the type (Not sure if I can do this)

**Option 2:** Configure one lambda function which can check type and then call the other lambda functions depending on its type

**Option 3:** Create separate queues for each lambda. Control which lambda processes the message by adding the message to the appropriate queue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Option 1: Configure SQS to trigger a different lambda function depending on the type

You can't know about the `type` until it is consumed by the lambda. So this one is not possible.

> Option 2: Configure one lambda function which can check type and then call the other lambda functions depending on its type

Yes it is the "possible" way of first option. but it may cost "more" depending on your usage. When you consume the sqs in batch mode, then you have to invoke multiple lambdas by making multiple checks.

> Option 3: Create separate queues for each lambda. Control which lambda processes the message by adding the message to the appropriate queue.

In my opinion, this could be the best option. You can configure different DLQ for each queue, set different batch size depending on your business rules, no need for extra lambda to increase "complexity".

Answer (score 9):

You should ***not*** configure multiple Lambda functions as triggers for a single SQS queue. This is because the message in SQS will be delivered to any one consumer and while this message is being processed by that consumer, it would not be visible to others. Thus, you wouldn't be able to decide which "type" of message goes to which function, so *Option 1* is invalid.

Both Option 2 and 3 should work fine. I would select *Option 2* if you do not expect that many messages to be delivered to your queue, thus not having to worry about [Lambda scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-scaling). Also note, multiple messages can be delivered in a single batch to the Lambda trigger, so you would have to implement your logic accordingly.

If you're expecting a large number of messages, then *Option 3* would be better suited.

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess Option 2 is still a bad idea for me because I would end up writing and maintaining 1 extra lambda function. There doesnt seem to be an extra cost with using more queues. So Option 3 seems to be a better fit

Answer (score 8):

Your best option here would be to not send the messages directly to the queue at all. You can use either SNS or EventBridge as the destination for the message. Then you should have one queue for each type of message. You can then subscribe each queue to the source (SNS or EventBridge) and only receive the messages that make sense for that queue. With EventBridge you can do a fair amount of filtering on the entire payload. For SNS you'd need to add the type to the attributes so it can be used for filtering.

[image]

Comment: The question is 1 year old and the solution is already implemented and running well on production. You suggest that I should not send messages to the queues directly but instead should use SNS or EventBridge but you dont explain why it is a bad idea. May I know why? Thanks.

Comment: Because SQS is designed for a single consumer. You have different consumers based on the message. That’s exactly what SNS or EventBridge are for. You send out a single message and the consumers decide what messages they want. By having the messages go to a single queue and then having something route the messages from there you are creating extra work and a definite anti pattern.

Comment: Option 3 does exactly that. Each queue has a single consumer. The consumers do not decide what they want. The publisher decides which queue would process the message and sends it to the appropriate queue.

Comment: That creates a tight coupling between the producer and consumers.

Answer (score 2):

I was asking the same question and found article below while I was considering EventBridge vs SQS.

In short, Option 1 is possible i.e. trigger a specific function based on event type. This came in Nov 2021.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/aws-lambda-event-filtering-amazon-sqs-dynamodb-kinesis-sources/

For more around price comparison see here: https://dev.to/aws-builders/should-we-consider-migrate-to-amazon-eventbridge-from-amazon-sns-sqs--4dgi

Answer (score 1):

You should probably post to an SNS topic and have multiple lambdas subscribe to the topic and process the event as they wish.

Comment: I don't think this is given enough credence, depending on the use case SNS is probably a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple lambda subscribing to SNS with different subscription filters looks best option here.
Benefits.

1. Minimum infra to manage.
2. Subscribers (Lambdas) do not have to worry about the filtering after receiving the message, each lambda will get specific message for processing based on the condition given in subscription filters.
3. SNS will take care of routing part based on the subscription filter.

Only additional piece you have to take care is make the type field available in Message Headers to apply to the subscription filters.

Comment: SNS is quite different from SQS, it's far from a drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of doing it with multiple lambda triggers, you should think more on your option #3.

The initial message can come to your original SQS and it should have one lambda trigger and it should pre-process that message. This lambda should pre-process the message and determine the type of message and send this message to 2nd level SQS (unique to each type) for process step.

[See this image for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfIwt.png)