# What is the best practice to architect tasks processing using AWS?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, task, background-service

I am wondering about how to configure AWS Lambda, SNS, and SQS for processing background tasks.

There are three ways I thought.

**Option 1**. A function called consumer can execute workers by receiving tasks from the queue.

**Option 2**. Send all tasks to SNS. One worker and one SQS receive and work from SNS.

**Option 3**. Directly forward the task to one SQS and one lambda from the APP.

[image: My paintings will help you understand]

The biggest concern is whether to directly invoke Lambda in the app or use task consumer using SQS or SNS.

My idea is from [Triggering multiple lambda functions from one SQS trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62349013/triggering-multiple-lambda-functions-from-one-sqs-trigger)

Comment: Are tasks 1, 2, and 3 totally different? Or do they only differ in input params?

Comment: Do you have three different "types" of tasks, each of which need to be processed differently (eg via different Lambda functions)?

Comment: @jellycsc That's actually my concern. The task itself is to send SMS messages, notifications of slacks, and so on when someone join the membership. I'm thinking about whether to branch out with parameters or invoke completely differently.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm not sure about that. I thought we should separate lambda because it has different functions. (eg send sms, black notifications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your current and future requirements:

**Options 1**: Choosing consumer lambda will allow you to add validations and manipulation in the event.
But your consumer lambda will be running until your worker lambdas are running.

**Option 2**: SNS gives you flexibility to add new events in future and new subscribers as well and your App will have to deal with only SNS.

**Option 3**: If you are sure in future there will be no such other lambdas. In this case your app need to have the configuration which type of event will go to which SQS.

You can choose any option based on your requirement but I will suggest you to choose option 2 as your app will be required to push notification to SNS only(Single integration). In SNS you can add filters for different types of event.
From SNS you can directly trigger lambda as well.

If you do not need output of lambda functions in your App you should use SNS/SQS for async processing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would be a good way if there were more than three tasks? And What do you think about the opinion that if a consumer like SNS or SQS goes wrong, there will be a problem with the worker and for that reason the option 3 is good?

Comment: Option 2 will be best if in future you want to add more tasks as you will be only required to add new subscription to your SNS. What do you mean by SNS or SQS goes wrong? Can you please elaborate? In option 3 you are also having SQS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For example, it reminds me that SNS dies due to AWS, or that SQS is not working due to incorrectly writing the lambda function that triggers the SQS.  I don't think of an exact example, but I'm worried that there's a risk in the sense that there's a bottleneck.

Comment: If you configure the application correctly once it should not give you any issue in future. SQS and SNS are both serverless services, so you not need to worry about maintenance and provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

The typical pattern is:

- Push jobs/tasks to an Amazon SQS queue
- Configure an AWS Lambda function to *subscribe* to the SQS queue
- Lambda will automatically execute the Lambda function for each message in the SQS queue

I guess this matches your **Option 1**, but with the AWS Lambda service acting as the "consumer" that triggers the individual Lambda functions.

If there are different types of inputs (eg three different tasks) that each require a different Lambda function, then create 3 separate queues each linked to its own Lambda function (your **Option 3**).

Inserting Amazon SNS in-between (shown in your **Option 2**) makes it easier to 'fork' information, such as adding another subscriber to each message in case they need to be processed in parallel. Otherwise, it is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So it's a better way to trigger on the app like option 3 without having to use a comsumer?

Comment: Definitely. AWS Lambda can manage activating the individual Lambda functions for you. There is no need to write a 'consumer'. If you were not using AWS Lambda, the architecture would be multiple workers running on Amazon EC2 instances. Each of those workers would be their own 'consumer', **pulling messages** off the queue. However, with Lambda, you would use a **push architecture**, with the AWS Lambda service triggering the individual functions.